# Set up member function that grants const access to members

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

I have a class with some huge objects that I need to access in a const fashion. To do that I have the getABC() member function that copies these objects to the outside world. Is it possible to directly access them, since the copy operations are very slow in my case? shared_ptr would be preferable, and also I want to avoid making tuples just to return them in the getABC()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class foo {
private:
    int a;
    vector<int> b; // HUGE OBJECT 
    vector<int> c; // HUGE OBJECT
public:
    foo(int a_, vector<int> b_, vector<int> c_) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) { }
    void printfoo() {
        cout << "a   = " << a << endl;
        cout << "b   = ";
        for(auto v:b) {
            cout << v << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "c   = ";
        for(auto v:c) {
            cout << v << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    void getABC(int & a_in, vector<int> & b_in, vector<int> & c_in ) const {
        a_in = a;
        b_in = b; // SLOW
        c_in = c; // SLOW
    }

};


int main() {

    int in = 4;
    vector<int> inA {1, 2, 3, 5};
    vector<int> inB {2, 2, 3, 5};

    foo bar(in, inA, inB);
    bar.printfoo();

//  GET THE MEMBERS
    int out = 0;
    vector<int> outA;
    vector<int> outB;
    bar.getABC(out, outA, outB);


//  PRINT 
    cout << "OUT = " << out;
    cout << "\nOUTA = ";
    for(auto const &v : outA ) {
        cout << v << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "OUTB = ";
    for(auto const &v : outA ) {
        cout << v << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need 1 function to get 3 pieces of data? Why not have 3 separate functions to return const references to the data?

Comment: They are always bundled, so I would have to write N function calls every time I need them. (Just lazy, but now I am curious if it is possible in a non-messy way)

Comment: If you want the public to access your members,move them to the public section.

Comment: Or return `tuple<const int&, const vector<int>&, const vector<int>&>`

Comment: Isn't this why we have iterators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to avoid making tuples just to return them in the getABC()

Why? It seems the most straightforward way to return references to multiple pieces of data:

```
tuple<const int&, const vector<int>&, const vector<int>&> getABC() const
{ return std::make_tuple(std::cref(a), std::cref(b), std::cref(c)); }


auto refs = bar.getABC();
for (auto& x : std::get<1>(refs))
  // ...
```

Or create a named struct to return instead:

```
struct DataRefs {
  int a;
  const std::vector<int>& b;
  const std::vector<int>& c;
};

DataRefs getABC() const  { return { a, b, c }; }
```

This has the advantage that you don't need to use `std::get<N>` to access the members, and can just use sensible names:

```
auto refs = bar.getABC();
for (auto& x : refs.b)
  // ...
```

From your comment maybe you want something like this, but this would be a dumb interface:

```
void getABC(const int*& pa, const std::vector<int>*& pb, const std::vector<int>*& pc) const
{
  pa = &a;
  pb = &b;
  pc = &c;
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
int* a;
std::vector<int>* b;
std::vector<int>* c;
bar.getABC(a, b, c);
for (auto& x : *b)
  // ...
```

As you can see, this is more verbose for the caller, and is just ugly and not idiomatic C++.

Or you could move the data into a separate sub-object:

```
class foo
{
  struct data
  {
    int a;
    std::vector<int> b;
    std::vector<int> c;
  };
  data m_data;

public:
  const data& getData() const { return m_data; };
};

auto& refs = bar.getData();
for (auto& x : refs.b)
  // ...
```

Comment: Is packing and unpacking free?

Comment: There is no "packing and unpacking", returning `tuple<T&, U&, V&>` is just like returning `std::pair<T&, U&>` except with three members. It's no more expensive and no cheaper than the `DataRefs` alternative above. Instead of worrying about the cost of imaginary packing and unpacking just write simple code that does the right thing.

Comment: Guys there is a fundamental issue here. To me, it seems that we cannot grant ownership through function arguments (only by return). I see your workarounds, but they do not answer my question.

Comment: There's no "fundamental issue". Of course you _can_ (see the edit to my answer) but it's not a good API. The idiomatic way to get something from a function is via its return value. I'm not sure what exactly you're asking if this doesn't answer it, but maybe the `getData()` alternative above is closer to what you want? If not, clarify your question!

Comment: The question is not clear, because of things like _"shared_ptr would be preferable"_ ... why? Are there some requirements you haven't told us, or you just like shared_ptr and think it would look nice here?

Answer (score 0):

You could have 3 separate functions that return const references (not necessary for the `int`):

```
class foo {
    ...
    int getA() const                { return a; }
    const vector<int>& getB() const { return b; }
    const vector<int>& getC() const { return c; }
};
```

These can even be inlined by the compiler so you don't need to actually put them anywhere. Just call `bar.getB()` whenever you need to use `b`. Even without inlining you're most likely not going to notice a performance hit.

Comment: Make the number of objects 50, and now you have to declare and define 50 member functions (and call).

Comment: 1 function with 50 arguments doesn't seem much better. This sounds like more of an issue with your design. You shouldn't have 1 class with all of this data.